# Save picture after being changed by progress bar

Tags: android, image, progress-bar

I am trying to have the picture changed based on the progress bars progress. Like so:

```
@Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0,
                            int progress, boolean arg2) {
                        audioManager.setStreamVolume(
                                AudioManager.STREAM_RING, progress, 0);

                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 0) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vibrate);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 1) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media1);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 2) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media1);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 3) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media1);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 4) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.media1);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 5) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 6) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 7) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);

                        }
                        if (volumeSeekbar1.getProgress() == 8) {
                            im112.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);

                        }
                    }
                });
```

As you can see the picture does change when I move the progress bar the problem is the minute i exit out the picture defaults back to what it was before. How do I make it save the
picture so if i exit out of the app it doesn't change back to the default icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store and restore the resource id. For example:
Store the id:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("final_image", R.drawable.sound);
editor.commit();
```

Read the id when your app resumed:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = default_image_id;
int image_id = sharedPref.getInt("final_image", defaultValue);
im112.setBackgroundResource(image_id);
```

Comment: i get this error when putting the first line of code under the volume seekbar progress one: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){}

Comment: You need to use your own Activity instance. Probably it is this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);